# How to handle errors but skip further processing within a stream?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In this scenario

```
this.http.call().pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
        doSomething();
    }),
    switchMap((data) => {
        doMoreThings();
    }),
);
```

It's possible to not execute the switchMap when the catchError block is executed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular synchronous http interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859416/angular-synchronous-http-interceptor)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what Observable you return from `catchError`'s callback.

If you return `empty()`. Then it won't trigger `switchMap` because `empty()` just completes and doesn't emit any `next` notifications.

You can also return `throwError(...)` that emits just an `error` notifications and no `next`'s.

Comment: I want to avoid the switchMap execution but I want to pass the request to the next handler.

Comment: Then just switch the order of operators.

Comment: Sorry, I mean pass the request to the next interceptor.

Comment: I don't know what that means. You can return inside `catchError` something like `handle.next()`

Comment: If I do handle.next(request) the next method inside pipe() is executed.

Comment: Then just switch the order of operators.

Comment: This is the same thing.